# Apache Velocity can not Initialize

Tags: java, velocity

When i try to initialize velocity engine using

```
VelocityEngine engine = new VelocityEngine();
engine.init();
```

I encounter the same error when i try

```
Velocity.init();
```

> org.apache.velocity.exception.VelocityException: Failed to initialize an instance of org.apache.velocity.runtime.log.ServletLogChute with the current runtime configuration.

What may cause this exception?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

try something like this:

```
Properties p = new Properties();
p.setProperty("resource.loader", "class");
p.setProperty("class.resource.loader.description", "Velocity Classpath Resource Loader");
p.setProperty("class.resource.loader.class", "org.apache.velocity.runtime.resource.loader.ClasspathResourceLoader");

    try {
      Velocity.init(p);
    } catch(...., and handle excpetion
  }
```

you'll now be able to call:

```
VelocityContext vContext = new VelocityContext(context);
//put things into vContext
StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
    try {
      template.merge(vContext, sw);
```

etc.

Comment: adding 

properties.setProperty 
    ("runtime.log.logsystem.class" 
    "org.apache.velocity.runtime.log.NullLogSystem");

did the trick

Comment: @Hamza: thanks a lot! Adding this setting to velocity.properties solved the problem

Answer (score 4):

The problem was solved putting the code below in my app:

```
java.util.Properties p = new java.util.Properties();
p.setProperty("runtime.log.logsystem.class", "org.apache.velocity.runtime.log.NullLogSystem");
try {
    Velocity.init(p);
} catch (Exception e) {
    System.out.println("FAIL!");
}
```

Comment: This works for me. Why does `org.apache.velocity.runtime.log.SystemLogChute` cause failure?

Answer (score 0):

The [LogManager source](http://velocity.apache.org/engine/devel/xref/org/apache/velocity/runtime/log/LogManager.html#206) suggests the originating exception is wrapped in the VelocityException. That wrapped exception should give you more info.

Note the related comment in the code.

```
/* If the above failed, that means either the user specified a
 * logging class that we can't find, there weren't the necessary
 * dependencies in the classpath for it, or there were the same
 * problems for the default loggers, log4j and Java1.4+.
 * Since we really don't know and we want to be sure the user knows
 * that something went wrong with the logging, let's fall back to the
 * surefire SystemLogChute. No panicking or failing to log!!
 */
```

Answer (score 0):

A clean way:

```
java.util.Properties props = new java.util.Properties();
props.setProperty(Velocity.RUNTIME_LOG_LOGSYSTEM_CLASS,    NullLogChute.class.getName());                        
Velocity.init(props);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
static {
    /** Initialisation du moteur velocity */
    Velocity.setProperty(Velocity.RUNTIME_LOG_LOGSYSTEM_CLASS, 
            "org.apache.velocity.runtime.log.NullLogSystem");
    Velocity.setProperty(RuntimeConstants.RESOURCE_LOADER,
            EjbConstants.VELOCITY_RESOURCE_LOADER_TYPE);
    Velocity.setProperty(EjbConstants.VELOCITY_CLASSPATH_RESOURCE_LOADER,
            ClasspathResourceLoader.class.getName());
}

public static String createXMLFlux(final RemiseEffetBean bean, 
        final String maquetteId) {

    try {
        final VelocityContext context = new VelocityContext();
        final StringWriter swOut = new StringWriter();

        // Initialisation
        Velocity.init();

        final Template template = Velocity.getTemplate(
                EjbConstants.XML_TEMPLATE_FILE, CharEncoding.UTF_8);

        context.put(EjbConstants.VELOCITY_REMISE_EFFET, bean);

        // id de la maquette pdf a generer
        context.put(EjbConstants.VELOCITY_MAQUETTE_ID, maquetteId);

        template.merge(context, swOut);

        return swOut.toString();
    } catch (final ResourceNotFoundException e) {
        LOGGER.error("La template n'a pas été trouvée", e);
    } catch (final ParseErrorException e) {
        LOGGER.error("Erreur du parsing de la template", e);
    } catch (final MethodInvocationException e) {
        LOGGER.error("Erreur lors de la substitution des données", e);
    } catch (final Exception e) {
        LOGGER.error("Erreur lors du traitement du fichier", e);
    }

    return null;
}
```