# java - unable to initialize velocity

Tags: java, linux, velocity

When I call Velocity.init() I get the following exception. I have included all dependencies, I have tried setting properties and using property files but all to no avail. any help?

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
at java.io.Reader.<init>(Reader.java:78)
at java.io.InputStreamReader.<init>(InputStreamReader.java:97)
at org.apache.commons.collections.ExtendedProperties.load(ExtendedProperties.java:543)
at org.apache.commons.collections.ExtendedProperties.load(ExtendedProperties.java:519)
at org.apache.velocity.runtime.RuntimeInstance.setDefaultProperties(RuntimeInstance.java:416)
at org.apache.velocity.runtime.RuntimeInstance.initializeProperties(RuntimeInstance.java:628)
at org.apache.velocity.runtime.RuntimeInstance.init(RuntimeInstance.java:261)
at org.apache.velocity.runtime.RuntimeSingleton.init(RuntimeSingleton.java:112)
at org.apache.velocity.app.Velocity.init(Velocity.java:74)
```

here is the calling code

```
import com.syntatik.roborm.RobormEntity;
import org.apache.velocity.VelocityContext;
import org.apache.velocity.Template;
import org.apache.velocity.app.Velocity;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.util.Properties;

public class Generator{
    protected VelocityContext context;

    public Generator(){
        Velocity.init();
        this.context = new VelocityContext();
    }
}
```

Comment: You are going to have to include some kind of code here.

Comment: We need the code for `Velocity.init()`. That's where the problem is. Specifically it is at Velocity.java line 74.

Comment: are you telling me this is a library bug?

Answer (score 2):

I have looked at the Velocity source code and can see that it's finding the default properties file on your classpath and then it's having trouble in Reader.java. With an IDE you should be able to get the source to Reader.java to find out why it's getting the NPE. Unfortunately at the moment I can't look at `Reader` to give you more information.

If you can't determine the cause of the NPE, I suggest you delete the default property file from your classpath and set the properties in code.

Have a look [at this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1586133/apache-velocity-can-not-initialize) for more information

Comment: unfortunatly i have already tried setting properties at runtime as mentioned above. i have no properties file on my classpath either.

Comment: From looking at the code, it looks like it's finding a default properties file in your classpath somewhere, so I would check that more carefully. YOu can actually debug this pretty easily by turning on the NullPointerException breakpoint. You should have the source for the JRE code, so you can see exactly why it's blowing up and then go back through the trace to see at least the variables of the Velocity code.